# Schedule Global Task by using static System.Timers

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I'm using System.Timers to schedule task. I find this working. But i'm not quite sure about is this ok to do it this way.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            timer1.Elapsed += timer1_Elapsed;
        }

        void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            Thread.Sleep(4000);
            // Do something. Example:
            File.AppendAllText("C:\\log.txt", DateTime.Now + "\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

By using this method, I can start the task anywhere in the application by calling this:

```
WebApplication2.Global.timer1.Start();
```

What do you think?

Comment: If you want other peoples thoughts on your code you should go ask on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: So you start timer to just run method, which stops timer? Why don't you just call method directly?

Comment: Would you considered using an existing solution in your ASP.NET application, instead of writing your own solution? If so, take a look at the [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com) open source project. You can it to call your web application back at your desired time. As an open source project, the complete source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/SageAnalytic/Revalee).